# Modify image uploaded in django 2.0 before the image is saved to disk

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a FileField for document uploads (e.g. images, pdfs, or videos). I use this line in my Document model:

```
storage_file_name = models.FileField('File name', upload_to=unique_file_path)
```

and in unique_file_path I change the name of the uploaded document to a unique file name. I find that I will be uploading some tiffs, which I need to change to jpeg or something that a browser can easily display.

I have been looking for the best way to convert the uploaded tiff file to jpeg. Is there a way to do it before the image is saved to the disk, or is the best way to use a

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Document)
```

and save the converted image over the saved tiff image?

At this point I am only using the admin pages and not any custom views (except by customizing the admin pages).

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do not want to save the file to the disk in the first place? Imagine that the file is rather huge, and your memory is "overflowing".

Comment: Just for efficiency sake - it takes time to save the image, then read it back, then save it again. It is already in memory, so it seems more deficient to change it before the initial save to disk. You make a good point about memory resources versus processing time. The images are not that big (~tens of MD), so in memory replacement just seems more responsive that going out to the disk three times.

Comment: personally I would do the conversion by an asynchronous task, since if somebody uploads a large image, it is possible that the connection times out due to the processing of the file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to hand the conversion off to an asynchronous task?